# React-redux Toolkit: Cannot set new state, when passing reducer as prop to another function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I am trying to use react redux toolkit and pass setter function to set new state on firebase's 'onAuthStateChanged'. The plan was to pass user's state (object or null) to reducer, depending if user is logged in or logged out. This is my first usage of redux, so I can't get why my code doesn't work. There is no errors, but in redux devtools state is always equal to null.

Configure Store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import userReducer from './utils/userReducer';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  }
})

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

My reducer:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {
        setUser: (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const {setUser} = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Where I am dispatching it:

```
  import { setUser } from '../utils/userReducer'
  import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { user } = await logInWithEmail(email, password)
    await setCurrentUser(() => dispatch(setUser))
  }
```

Firebase function, where I am trying to use reducer:

```
export const setCurrentUser = async (setUser) => {
    await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
        setUser(currentUser)
    })
}
```

I understand, that with useContext it would be much easier, but I am trying to learn redux by implying it.

Comment: can you show  `configureStore`? how it's configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that:

```
import { setUser } from '../utils/userReducer'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { user } = await logInWithEmail(email, password)
  // This line updated
  await setCurrentUser((currentUser) => dispatch(setUser(currentUser)))
}
```

The reason:

your `setCurrentUser` function prop `setUser` is just function `() => dispatch(setUser)`, but this function does not receive any prop, and `dispatch(setUser)` does not do anything. you need to pass value (`payload`) to reducer function.

Additionally, try passing `dispatch` itself as prop and dispatch inside of `onAuthStateChanged`.

```
export const setCurrentUser = async (dispatch) => {
  await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    dispatch(setUser(currentUser))
  })
}
```

import `setUser` reducer function if `handleLogin` and `setCurrentUser` function is in different files separately.

Comment: I've tried both variants, and they both work. Now I get currentUser obj as a payload, but state somehow stays the same - null. Thank you for detailed explanation.